# Undefining a class and all its methods in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clos, ccl

I would like to undefine a class and all of its methods but after a quite thorough search on Googlore I have been unable to find a clue about how to do this.

I am using an implementation of Commmon Lisp called CCL (Clozure CL).

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?  Though it doesn't look like there's a standard way to do it, perhaps Rainer Joswigs's answer pointed you toward a CCL specific solution?  Or maybe something else worked altogether?

Answer (score 6):

This is a rather interesting question.  Although, as [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619701/1281433) points out, you can use `(setf (find-class 'class-name) nil)` to make things like `(make-instance 'class-name)` stop working, that doesn't actually delete the class.  You could, for instance, save the earlier result of `(find-class …)` somewhere else:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defclass foo () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO>
CL-USER> (defmethod show ((x foo))
           (print "x is a foo"))
STYLE-WARNING: Implicitly creating new generic function SHOW.
#<STANDARD-METHOD SHOW (FOO) {1002BFD321}>
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo-class* (find-class 'foo))
*FOO-CLASS*
CL-USER> (show (make-instance 'foo))

"x is a foo" 
"x is a foo"
CL-USER> (setf (find-class 'foo) nil)
NIL
CL-USER> (make-instance 'foo)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "There is no class named ~ .. {1002FDBC61}>.
CL-USER> (make-instance *foo-class*)
#<#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO> {1003217F91}>
```

I'm not sure whether there's actually any way to delete a class from the system, and it's not clear exactly what it would mean to do so, since it would have to address the issue of what to do with any existing instances of the class.

`(setf find-class)` also doesn't delete any methods that have been specialized for the class.  Continuing the example just started, as we can still call `show` on instances of the class, and we can still retrieve the specialized methods:

```lisp
CL-USER> (show (make-instance *foo-class*))

"x is a foo" 
"x is a foo"
CL-USER> (find-method #'show '() (list *foo-class*))
#<STANDARD-METHOD SHOW ((CLASS #<STANDARD-CLASS FOO>)) {1003A7D081}>
```

However, you can remove applicable methods from a generic function using [REMOVE-METHOD](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_met.htm):

```lisp
CL-USER> (remove-method #'show (find-method #'show '() (list *foo-class*)))
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION SHOW (0)>
CL-USER> (show (make-instance *foo-class*))
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<There is no applicable method for the generic function ~2I~_~S~ .. {1002EA5731}>.
```

In the Common Lisp Object System (CLOS), methods don't belong to classes, so it doesn't make sense to speak of "[undefining] a class and all of its methods."  Rather, CLOS has generic functions, and the programmer defines methods that specialize the generic function. As the above examples show, while there may not be a portable way to undefine a class, you can remove the methods that are specialized for instances of that class, but you'll have to track down what they are.  For more information, have a look at:

- [Chapter 7. Objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_.htm) of the HyperSpec and familiarize yourself with some of these concepts, because they do differ from what you find in many languages that are called object oriented.  You might find a more gentle introduction in
- [Chapter 16. Object Reorientation: Generic Functions](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) and [Chapter 17. Object Reorientation: Classes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html) from Peter Seibel's [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).  The book is a great reference, and the whole thing is available for free online.

This topic has also been discussed on comp.lang.lisp:

- [undefining a class](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/hzQ7RRTK4Lg)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`find-class`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_c.htm):

```
(setf (find-class 'myclass) nil)
```

However, this will not destroy the class object, nor will it remove the corresponding methods.

The full process would require [unintern](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_uninte.htm)ing the `myclass` symbol and the slot names of the class - but you might be using those symbols elsewhere, so be careful!

You will also have to [`remove-method`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_met.htm) from the generic functions for which you defined them.

In short, this is a huge enterprise, certainly not worth the effort.

Just restart your Lisp session.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily undefine the class.  For instance, the value of `(find-class 'myclass)` might have been saved elsewhere, and it doesn't remove any of the methods specialized on `'myclass` either.

Answer (score 2):

This is not portable, but in an IDE like LispWorks:

- use the class browser, list all methods for the class without inherited ones, select the methods, from the *methods* menu call *undefine*
- in the editor select the `defclass` form, in the *definitions* menu call *undefine*

The CCL IDE might not have these commands, but *SLIME* + *Emacs* might have something similar.

Comment: Interestingly, after doing `(defclass foo () ()) (defvar *foo* (find-class 'foo))` and then undefining the class in this way, `(make-instance *foo*)` still returns an object along the lines of `#<CLOS::DELETED-CLASS-OBJECT ...>`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Sure, you probably can specialize on `clos::deleted-class-object`.  I was just pointing out that (i) some of the things that the naïve approach `(setf (find-class 'foo) nil)` doesn't handle (e.g., saving the class elsewhere) aren't handled by this approach (you can still `(make-instance *foo*)` without error), but that (ii) it's still doing something more useful, because `(method-specialized-for-foo (make-instance *foo*))` _will_ signal an error because `(make-instance *foo*)` is no longer a `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this:

Standard Generic Function [`#'make-instances-obsolete`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_i_1.htm#make-instances-obsolete) in the HyperSpec.
Take special note of how it interacts with `#'defclass` upon redefining a 
"standard class".

Also look at `#'fmakunbound`, `#'unintern`, `#'delete-package` and

```
(remove-method
  (find-method #'<generic-function-symbol>
               '(:before :after :<some-other-qualifier-you-may-be-interested-in>)
               ;; specializers are the classes or eq specializers
               ;; in method lambda lists
               '(<first-specializer> <second-specializer-and-so-on>)))
```

where this last piece of code is close to [Joshua Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619909).